# Java Regex: Selecting balanced bracket data

Tags: java, regex

```
{{ info {{ abc}} {{ last}} }} {{ fast}}
```

in this string i need to just extract the data such that the starting and ending brackets balances. i.e in this case i would need

1. `{{ info {{ abc}} {{ last}} }}`
2. `{{ fast}}`

the regex i m using currently is

```
(\\ {\\{.*\\}\\}) *
```

but it gives me the whole string rather then the one i expect. how to do it correctly?

```
String line="{{ Infobox {{aks}} {{ska}}  }} akshat {{ las}}";
String pattern;
System.out.println(line);
Pattern r=Pattern.compile("(\\{\\{.*\\}\\})*");
Matcher m=r.matcher(line);
```

the output is the whole string... not the one i expected

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to solve this using Java regexes.

Regular expressions (in the mathematical sense) cannot parse input against a recursive grammar.  And you require a recursive grammar to describe a language (such as this one) in which arbitrarily nested brackets are balanced.

While Java regexes are more powerful than mathematical ones, they still don't support recursion.  (Regex engines in some languages do ... but you asked for a solution in Java.)

---

You could create a regex that handles a *finite* number of levels of nested brackets, but it is going to be ugly and inefficient ... especially if you have to deal bad input with unbalanced brackets!  (And that the efficiency concern applies to hypothetical solutions involving recursive regexes too ...)

However, I recommend tokenizing the string and doing a simple ad-hoc parse that counts the brackets levels and emits a result when the level returns to zero.  It is a simple coding problem: see @Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer for a starting point.  (But note that he's not dealt with 2 error cases ...)

Comment: (at least not Java regexes. PHP/Perl/.NET regex engines *can* do recursive matching). None of the actual regex engines in use today are limited to regular grammars in the strict mathematical sense anyway, so regularity isn't really a criterion any more.

Comment: However, this is true for Java regexes.

Comment: so is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with regex. But if you are interested in other solutions I can suggest

```
    String s = "{{ info {{ abc}} {{ last}} }} {{ fast}}";
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int balance = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(c);
        if (c == '{') {
            balance++;
        } else if (c == '}' && --balance == 0) {
            l.add(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(l);
```

output

```
[{{ info {{ abc}} {{ last}} }},  {{ fast}}]
```